# Не приходит почта

Tags: smtp, email

Здравствуйте, подскажите, почему у меня с сайта почта приходит на ящик (с формы обратной связи), а с внешнего ящика ничего не приходит. Ошибка такая:

> This message was created automatically
> by mail delivery software.
>
> A message that you sent could not be
> delivered to one or more of its
> recipients. This is a permanent error.
> The following address(es) failed:
>
> info@pharma-lex.com
>     SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:[info@site.ru](mailto:info@site.ru):
>     host mx15.ukraine.com.ua [91.222.136.100]: 554 5.7.1
> [info@site.ru](mailto:info@site.ru):
>     Relay access denied

Comment: Опять не уложился в 10 сообщений. 
"А как заранее проверить будет ли все работать на новом хостинге?"

1. Обратиться в тех. поддержку, и задать вопрос.  
2. Перейти на проверенный хостинг. Опережая Ваш вопрос, я использую fullspace.ru поддерживает python/django/wsgi.  
С проблемой на хостинге, как у Вас, имею дело впервые, возможно, тех. поддержка помогла бы Вам найти причину.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relay access denied - запрещен релэй от данного сервера. Письма с других серверов пряходят? Попробуйте отправить тестое письмо с другого сервера.

Comment: Я на эту почту хочу прислать, не принимает. Исходящая почта работает.

Comment: Я Вас понял, попробуйте отправить тестовое письмо с другого почтового сервера, чтобы был другой ip-адрес и домен.

Comment: Так с разных почт уже пробовал, ни с одной не приходит

Comment: Почтовый ящик на который вы пытаетесь отправить письмо существует?

Comment: Да, с формы обратной связи с сайта на него письма приходят. С внешней почты (mail, yandex и т.д.) не приходит ничего.

Comment: Попробовал зацепиться телнетом к smtp. Похоже, что для вашего домена запрещен релей на этом smtp сервере.

Comment: Если это Ваш smtp сервер, и к нему имеется доступ, то нужно разрешить релэй на почтовые ящики в домене pharma-lex.com. Если это хостинг, и доступа к почтовой системе вы не имеете, обратиться в тех. поддержку или сменить хостинг.

Comment: Да, это хостинг, но техподдержку я там не нашел)) Получается нужно сменить хостинг на адекватный и с техподдержкой? А как заранее проверить будет ли все работать на новом хостинге?